# how to correctly insert rows at the beginning of the table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created sqlite database and i use ContentValues to insert records into it from a file, the file contains 689 lines which means i will insert
689 records into the databse i created.

the problem i am facing is, despite i initially delete all the records from the databse, each time i call the "populate()" method posted belwo i
receive "total rows: 0" as shown in the output below, but the inserted rowid never starts from 0 as shown below in the output.

in other words, assume i insert 10 records to a databse table, initially it will contain 10 records and the first and last rowid will be 1 and 10
respectively. and when i delete all the rows from the databse and insert another 10 records, the rowid of the first and last row will be 11 and 19 respectively
and i think, the rowid of the first and last row should be 1 and 9 respectively

please let me know why that is happening and how to solve it

**code**:

```
public void populate(Context context, File file, SQLiteHelper sqliteHelper) {
    this.mCtx = context;
    this.mSQLiteHelper = sqliteHelper;
    this.mSQLiteHelper.deleteALLRows();

    Log.i(TAG, "total rows: " + this.mSQLiteHelper.getTotalRowsInDB());//return 0 rows..which is understandable
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
try {
        while ( (line = this.mBR.readLine()) !=  null ) {
            Log.v(TAG, "line: " + line);

            params = line.split(",");

            cv.put(this.mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.cv_col1), params[0]);
            cv.put(this.mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.cv_col2), params[1]);
            cv.put(this.mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.cv_col3), params[2]);
            cv.put(this.mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.cv_col4), params[3]);

            if (!wdb.isOpen()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "wdb will be opened");
                wdb = this.mSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }

            rowId = wdb.insert(this.mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.str_sqlite_table_name), null, cv);

            if (rowId != -1) {
                Log.v(TAG, "row inserted correctly. rowid: " + rowId);
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "row insertion error");
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "params[0]: " + params[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, "params[1]: " + params[1]);
            Log.d(TAG, "params[2]: " + params[2]);
            Log.d(TAG, "params[3]: " + params[3]);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**output**:

```
02-04 15:07:24.182 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication I/Populator: total rows: 0

02-04 15:07:24.182 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication V/Populator: line: 163816,49.3478675,8.4643171,120
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication V/Populator: row inserted correctly. rowid: 1
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[0]: 163816
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[1]: 49.3478675
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[2]: 8.4643171
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[3]: 120
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication V/Populator: line: 163817,49.3455829,8.467746,120
02-04 15:07:24.212 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication V/Populator: row inserted correctly. rowid: 689
02-04 15:07:24.222 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[0]: 163817
02-04 15:07:24.222 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[1]: 49.3455829
02-04 15:07:24.222 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[2]: 8.467746
02-04 15:07:24.222 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[3]: 120
....
....
....
02-04 15:07:29.972 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication V/Populator: line: 456947,49.0559242,8.4985024,120
02-04 15:07:29.982 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication V/Populator: row inserted correctly. rowid: 690
02-04 15:07:29.982 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[0]: 456947
02-04 15:07:29.982 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[1]: 49.0559242
02-04 15:07:29.982 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[2]: 8.4985024
02-04 15:07:29.982 27741-27741/com.example.com.myapplication D/Populator: params[3]: 120
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The rowid says 690 in that last log. You're having a problem with the autoincrementing row id?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar in my app and my id restart from 1 when I delete all the rows :
I think you should not declare id as autoincrement but just primary key

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "create table "+TABLE_NAME+ " "+
                    "(id integer primary key, name text,description text)"
            );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The very first thing is when you have a auto increment id on a row and once it is incremented it will not decrement automatically even if the row is deleted.
I would suggest you to use **truncate table** command in place of delete command (only if you want to delete entire table data )
What truncate does is it drops your table and recreates it thus your auto increment id will also be reset and **start from 0 again**.
Truncate is also faster than delete.